# I keep receiving [RCTCxxBridge jsContextRef] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8af262f4f0' was thrown from JS thread

Tags: react-native, realm

I just keep receiving this when I update my react native version to the last version

```
Exception '-[RCTCxxBridge jsContextRef]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8af262f4f0' was thrown from JS thread

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start
0x0
```

my versions are the following:

```
"react-native": "0.58.3",
"react": "16.6.3",
"realm": "^2.23.0"
```

The project is build successfully, but the problem appear in the emulator

Answer (score 3):

I find realm team are working to update their version to fix the changes because RN 0.58 updated JavaScriptCore and it is now needed as a framework dependency, so it was a major change in.

Thus they are working on https://github.com/realm/realm-js/pull/2242 and we need to wait till completed and released.

Comment: I end up using RXDB at the current moment @Pieter888 and it works fine on RN 0.58.4

Comment: I updated my package.json to use the branch  "realm": "realm/realm-js#tg/npm-5" and it's working now, thx

Comment: @valR which node version are you using?

Comment: @boppa v10.13.0